# Multiplying a sparse matrix with sparse vector (efficient way)

Tags: python, matrix, vector, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a sparse matrix **M** of size **N*N** with **Nd** non-zero elements and a sparse vector **A** of size **N*1** with **Na** non-zero elements. (N is large)
I want to calculate the matrix multiplication **B=MA**.

---

I use the sparse matrix representation in scipy.sparse. **P=csr_matrix(M)**. Then I do **B=P.dot(A)**.

I know the complexity of this operation is **O(Nd)**. It seems that **A** is regarded as a dense vector in the calculation. Because when I change the number **Na**, the computation time of this multiplication does not change. But the vector **A** is also sparse. Is there any efficient ways to perform this multiplication with less computation time.

In my simulation, **M** is fix. The vectors **A** are differents but they are all sparse.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "In my simulation, M is fix. The vectors A are differents but they are all sparse." - stack up your A matrices into one sparse matrix and do one sparse matrix multiplication.

Comment: In fact, the vector A2 is based on the result of MA1. I do not know all the A at same time. It is calculated step by step.

Comment: Just to be clear, is `A` also a `csr_matrix`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534970/numpy-matrix-product-sparse-matrices has some timings of different multiplication methods.