# Numpy matrix product - sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

Let us consider a matrix A as a diagonal matrix and a matrix B a random matrix, both with size N x N.
We want to use the sparse properties of the matrix A to optimize the dot product, i.e. dot(B,A).

However if we compute the product using the sparcity properties of the matrix A, we cannot see any advantage (and it is much slower).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
# Matrix sizes
N = 1000

#-- matrices generation --
A = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=complex)
for i in range(N):
    A[i][i] = np.random.rand()
B = np.random.rand(N,N)

#product
%time csr_matrix(B).dot(A)
%time np.dot(B,A)
```

Results:

CPU times: user 3.51 s, sys: 8 ms, total: 3.52 s
Wall time: 3.74 s

CPU times: user 348 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 348 ms
Wall time: 230 ms

How to do it correctly?

Comment: `%time csr_matrix(B).dot(A)` does first a conversion of `B` to a `csr_matrix`. Is that something you want to time as well?

Comment: But B is not a sparse matrix. csr_matrix should only be applied to sparse matrices.

Comment: I would say go with the sparse matrix method only when the matrix is extremely big and sparse. `np.dot` is extremely efficient under normal scenarios.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain my problem correctly. I want to do np.dot(B,A) taking advantage of A being sparse.

Comment: But you do the conversion to a sparse matrix format in the timing. This results in this difference.

Comment: So you're saying that being sparse is not an advantage, because you always have to make the conversion (which I don't believe).
Another thing is if you change the order of the matrices, the product is much faster (however the result is not what we want).

Comment: See my answer for a more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that you convert `B` to a sparse matrix during the timing (minor effect) and even worse, that `dot` is not aware of the fact, that `A` is sparse. If you were to do the conversion before the dot product the sparse dot product is actually faster:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
# Matrix sizes
N = 1000

#-- matrices generation --
A = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=complex)
for i in range(N):
    A[i][i] = np.random.rand()
B = np.random.rand(N,N)

Asparse = csr_matrix(A)
Bsparse = csr_matrix(B)

%timeit np.dot(B, A)
%timeit csr_matrix(B).dot(A)
%timeit Bsparse.dot(A)
%timeit csr_matrix.dot(B, Asparse)
%timeit csr_matrix.dot(Bsparse, Asparse)
```

Gives:
`np.dot(B, A)`: 1 loop, best of 3: 414 ms per loop
`csr_matrix(B).dot(A)`: 1 loop, best of 3: 2.22 s per loop
`Bsparse.dot(A)`: 1 loop, best of 3: 2.17 s per loop
`csr_matrix.dot(B, Asparse)`: 10 loops, best of 3: 32.5 ms per loop
`csr_matrix.dot(Bsparse, Asparse)`: 10 loops, best of 3: 28 ms per loop

As you can see the sparse dot product is much faster in all cases where `A` is in a sparse matrix format which is making `dot` aware of the fact, that `A` is sparse. In your timing, the function is actually doing a conversion of `B` to a sparse format and then a dot product with a dense matrix `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Done right, sparse dot is faster - if the matrices are indeed sparse.  But you can't just throw the arrays into the `csr_matrix.dot` function.

```
In [68]: N=1000
In [69]: from scipy import sparse
In [70]: A=np.eye(N)         # the diagonal is more interesting than all zeros
In [71]: B=np.random.rand(N,N)
```

Base case - dense matrix product

```
In [72]: timeit np.dot(B,A)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.8 ms per loop
```

This time is the same for all arrays of the same size (e.g `dot(B,B)`, `dot(A,A)`).

Make sparse matrix from both.  `As` has lots of zeros, `Bs` has none, but it is in sparse format

```
In [73]: As=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
In [74]: Bs=sparse.csr_matrix(B)
```

Note the conversion times; they are not trivial

```
In [101]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop
In [102]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix(B)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.1 ms per loop
```

Matrix product with the csr matrices can be faster. I'll use the `Bs.dot(As)` form because it's clearer. `Bs*As` and `np.dot(Bs,As)` are equivalent.  But don't try `np.dot(Bs,A)`

```
In [107]: timeit Bs.dot(As)
100 loops, best of 3: 19 ms per loop

In [112]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix(B).dot(sparse.csr_matrix(A)).A
10 loops, best of 3: 94.1 ms per loop
```

Noticeably better than the dense version, but marginally better if we include the conversion times.

But note that times vary widely depending on the sparsity of the matrices

```
In [108]: timeit As.dot(Bs)
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop
In [109]: timeit As.dot(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.82 ms per loop
In [110]: timeit As.dot(As)
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 µs per loop
In [111]: timeit Bs.dot(Bs)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.83 s per loop
```